# jQuery toggle div from select option with append method issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div with <\select> drop down. And from the Drop down if I select limited it opens a div with Input and it works fine.

I also added one link **+ Add New** and clicking on the **+add new** creates a **new** div with the <\select> drop down which should work same as before but when I select limited from the new drop down it effects the previous one. How can I make it so that it only open for the div I am working and do no effect other divs no meter how many I create.

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/jnLfh/18/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="row">   
    <select class="optionSelector">
        <option>-Select-</option>
        <option value="limited">Limited</option>
        <option>Unlimited</option>
     </select>

    <div class="limited" > 
        <input type="number">
     </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.add').click(function() {
 $(".wrapper").append('<div class="row"><select class="optionSelector"><option>-Select-</option><option value="limited">Limited</option><option>Unlimited</option></select><div class="limited" ><input type="number"></div></div>');
});

$(".wrapper").on('change', '.optionSelector', function(){
       $('.limited').hide();
       $('.' + $(this).val()).show();     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get only the dropdown next to it

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/jnLfh/23/)**

```
$(".wrapper").on('change', '.optionSelector', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.limited').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".wrapper").on('change', '.optionSelector', function(){
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.limited').css('display', $(this).val()=='limited'?'block':'none');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zW99n/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

The `$('.limited')` selector gets all the elements with the class `.limited`.

Comment: How does this even remotely answer the question?